# C++ - pointer and array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm new to c++, I have a question about pointer and array

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    int a[5] = {1,7,-1,0,2};
    int b[5] = {7,5,3,4,2};
    int c[5] = {1,4,5,3,1};

    *(&a[2] + (&c[5] - 7 - &c[0]))= a[1];
    *(&a[3] + (&c[5] - 7 - &c[0]))= b[1];
    *(&a[4] + (&c[5] - 7 - &c[0]))= c[1];
    int x = a[0] - a[1] + a[2] - a[3];


    printf ("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is that x = 6? thx

Comment: There is no `y` in your code - I guess you mean `x`?

Comment: Is this homework or an interview question?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Where did this code come from?

Comment: Are you writing for an obfuscated code contest?

Comment: @Ferry, do you understand what each line does?  If not, ask us a question about the first line you don't understand.  If yes, then you should be able to answer this question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning with:

```
*(&a[2] + (&c[5] - 7 - &c[0]))= a[1];
```

First we notice the subexpression `(&c[5] - 7 - &c[0])` is used multiple times.
`(&c[5] - 7 - &c[0])` can be rearranged as `(&c[5]- &c[0] - 7 )`, which is the address of the fifth int of `c`, minus the address of the 0th int of `c`, which results in `5`*, so the expression is `(5-7)` or `-2`.
`(&a[2] -2)` is the address of the second index minus two, which is the same as `&a[0]`.  So `*(&a[2] + (&c[5] - 7 - &c[0]))` is `a[0]`.
By extrapolation, the rest of the code is as follows:

```
              //a is {1,7,-1,0,2};
a[0] = a[1];  //a is {7,7,-1,0,2};
a[1] = b[1];  //a is {7,5,-1,0,2};
a[2] = c[1];  //a is {7,5, 4,0,2};
```

So then we get to the final equation:

```
int x = a[0] - a[1] + a[2] - a[3];
```

and when we find the values in those positions of the array:

```
int x = 7 - 5 + 4 - 0;
```

Which results in `6`.

*the addresses are not *actually* 5 apart (they're usually 20 or 40), but when you do subtraction of `int` pointers, it results in the number of `int`s between them, which is five.

Comment: I think it's not quite right to say that "(&c[5]- &c[0] - 7 ), which is the address of the fifth element of c, minus the address of the 0th element of c, which is five".  These are pointers to ints, so the address difference is more likely to be 4 times what you're saying.  Luckily, C doesn't take a simple address difference.  Pointer differences instead return array index differences (basically), so the difference is still the 5 you were expecting.

Comment: Since the rest of the post is complicated I originally decided to gloss over that point.  However, I have corrected the wording, and added a side-comment to explain.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that your operations logically imply it / you are invoking undefined behavior somewhere.

But the *true* answer is that **nobody writes code like this**.

- If you find this in an interview, call their bluff and laugh. If they're serious about it, leave.
- If you find this in real code, post it in thedailywtf. Then refuse to touch it.

Comment: This really ought to be a comment. You are quite right in what you say, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're abosulutely right, marked as CW.

Comment: +1 for "call their bluff and laugh".

Comment: After reviewing this code a fifth time, I wonder if there is actually undefined behavior anywhere.  There's pointer arithmetic that results in a negative value, but I don't think that's UB.  The rest seems wierd, but defined.

Comment: @MooingDuck I think you're right. +1 on your answer for the awesome effort (I can't understand how in 94 views, so far only 1 person upvoted you).

Answer (score 2):

The indirection operator & is used to refer to the address of a variable

The operator * can be used to refer to targeted

**Operator &**

```
int c : variable integer
&c : memory address of the variable
```

**Operator ***

```
int *c : pointer to an integer variable
*c: content pointed to by c
```

The result 6 is product of:

```
(&c[5] - 7 - &c[0])  is always equal to -2, 

*(&a[2] + (&c[5] - 7 - &c[0]))= a[1];  // a[0]=a[1]  
*(&a[3] + (&c[5] - 7 - &c[0]))= b[1];  // a[1]=b[1]  
*(&a[4] + (&c[5] - 7 - &c[0]))= c[1];  // a[2]=c[1]
```

The result

```
a[0]=7, a[1]=5, a[2]=4 and a[3]=0
6 = 7 - 5 + 4 -0
```